# C# SQL Restore Open Connection cannot close

Tags: c#, sql, database-restore

I run the following code and it tells me that there is already an open connection to the database.

```
data source=ws-server02;initial catalog=SL_M2009;
user id=sa;password=gregfhh
```

I checked 10 times but didn't find anything which is open.  Maybe my code opens a connection which blocks the Restore?

The error codes are here:

1. http://grabilla.com/04313-7f69772a-f65c-4a3c-81c3-c118f39ea907.html
2. http://grabilla.com/04313-4f78e5cc-27e3-4155-b92f-1da7976afdb7.html

What can I do now for getting the Restore completed? Below is the relevant code block.

```
string dbconnectstring = data source=ws-server02;initial catalog=SL_M2009;user id=sa; password=myownpw;
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(dbconnectstring);
Server sqlServer = new Server(new ServerConnection(sqlConn));

MessageBox.Show("Server Status: "
+ sqlServer.Status
+ "\r\nDatabase Name: "
+ sqlConn.Database + " Active Connections: "
+ sqlServer.GetActiveDBConnectionCount(sqlConn.Database));


Restore restoreDB = new Restore();
String file = NewestFile(dbsource);
restoreDB.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
restoreDB.Database = sqlConn.Database;
restoreDB.Devices.AddDevice(NewestFile(dbsource), DeviceType.File);
restoreDB.ReplaceDatabase = true;
restoreDB.NoRecovery = true;
restoreDB.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```

Comment: at which line you are getting error ??

Comment: You don't need to provide the *actual* username passwords here !!!

Comment: @AftabAhmed On the last line it tells me

Comment: @huMptyduMpty why? its not a local sql server its in my network so :s

Comment: @user3428118: I mean in the question!! Of course you need in your actual code, but when you asking question just put a some dummy text i.e. `passwrod=xxxx` etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code hope it will work

```
ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
MessageBox.Show("Server Status: "
            + sqlServer.Status
            + "\r\nDatabase Name: "
            + sqlConn.Database + " Active Connections: "
            + sqlServer.GetActiveDBConnectionCount(sqlConn.Database));
Restore rstDatabase = new Restore();
rstDatabase.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
rstDatabase.Database = databaseName;
BackupDeviceItem bkpDevice = new BackupDeviceItem(backUpFile, DeviceType.File);
rstDatabase.Devices.Add(bkpDevice);
rstDatabase.ReplaceDatabase = true;
rstDatabase.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
```